# Exponential map - Geometric interpretation

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, intuition

Let $(M,\nabla)$ be an affine manifold and $p\in M$. The exponential map at $p$ is defined as $\text{exp}_p:\mathcal{E}\to M$ such that $v\to \gamma_v(1)$
with $\mathcal{E}=\{v\in T_pM:\gamma_v(1) \text{ is defined }\}$ and $\gamma_v$ the unique geodesic s.t. $\gamma_v(0)=p$ and $\gamma_v'(0)=v$

In which book can I find a geometric motivation of this definition??

Comment: For Lie groups admitting a bi-invariant Riemannian metric, the Riemannian exponential on $T_eM$ corresponds with the Lie group exponential, which in the case of matrices is just the usual exponential. I think that the name comes from this (although this is not a geometric motivation)

Comment: You don't consider polar coordinates in the plane to be geometric motivation...? :)